# Search bar is working correctly but the Link from search bar is not working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to search for a professional according to location and category.  The search bar is filtering the results correctly, but the problem is that when the result is shown after filtering then this result is shown in link.  When I click on the result which is shown in link, the link is not working.  This link does not redirect the page on the given path.  How can I solve this problem?

Here is the code of my view file:

```
<section class="search">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid my_searchbar">
      <div class="container my_searchbar_container">
        <div class="nav nav-justified navbar-search navbar-nav">                  
          <form class="search navbar-search" method="post" action="index.html" >
            <div class="input-group">            
              <input type="text" name="search_area" id="search_area" placeholder="Search Area" class="form-control input-lg"> 
              <input type="text" name="search_pro" id="search_pro" placeholder="Search Professional Category" class="form-control input-lg">        
              <ul id="show_search_pro" class="results" >
              </ul>
              <div class="input-group-btn">
              </div>
            </div>  
          </form>         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is my javascript of this view file:
In this I am also using ajax and keyup method to show the filtered results.

```
$('#search_pro').keyup(function(){
    var location_field = $('#search_area');
    var search_cal_field = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/JustClick/User/search_professional',
        cache : false,
        dataType : 'html',
        data :{
               location_id:location_field.val(), 
               category_id:search_cal_field.val()
              },
        success:function(data){
            $('#show_search_pro').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is code of my controller:

```
public function search_professional()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        $professional = $this->UserModel->search_professional($this->input->post('location_id',true),$this->input->post('category_id',true));
        foreach ($professional as $row) 
        {
            echo '

                <li>
                    <a class="s_pro" href="'.site_url('Professional/show_professional_detail/'.$row->pro_id).'">'.$row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname.'<br /><span>Description...</span></a></i>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in the browser console ?

Comment: NO,there is no error on browser console

Comment: Help me how i solve it